# Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am getting following error while doing ng serve.

Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "undefined".

My package json is looks like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
```

Here is my `ng -v` information

```
  ng -v
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.22-1
node: 8.2.1
os: darwin x64
```

Comment: You cannot use @angular/compiler **7.1.4** with @angular/core **2.2.3**. Get your versions in sync. You should start by moving your code to new versions of everything Angular.

Comment: I have just started. what should i do make two of same @angular/compiler 7.1.4 with @angular/core 7.1.4?

Comment: Start here: https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

The project needs a dev dependency for @angular/compiler-cli.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli@<your angular version>
```